# Excel cross referencing multiple data sets across multiple indices

Tags: excel

I'm trying to semi-automate identifying when members of a distributed squad have public holidays (or other events) that fall between two specific dates.  I have several datasets in use:

1. I have a list of public holidays with **DATE** and **LOCATION** in two columns, which looks something like:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | DATE | LOCATION |
| 3 | 19/09/2023 | INDIA |
| 4 | 29/09/2023 | AUSTRALIA |
| 5 | 02/10/2023 | INDIA |
| 6 | 23/10/2023 | NEW ZEALAND |
| 7 | *etc* | *etc* |

2. I have a list of squad members across columns with their location in the second row, something like:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Rob | Sam | Tim | Grace | Elinor |
| 2 | Location | Australia | India | Australia | New Zealand | India |

3. I also have a start and end date:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start Date | End Date |
| 2 | 02/09/2023 | 16/10/2023 |

What I'd like to do is have a row underneath each team member that will automatically indicate if there is a public holiday in country that falls on a date between the start and end date, and if there are multiple then providing a count.

I have a couple of pretty hacky ideas that may work involving a bunch of "helper" columns, but I'd like to find a more tidy solution (hopefully in a single formula) if there is one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, you could also just keep things simple and use the `COUNTIFS` function. For example:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A5, ">="&D2, A2:A5, "<="&E2, B2:B5, E5:I5)
```

[image: countifs.png]

**Note:** only one formula was required in cell `E6` because all locations in the range `E5:I5` were passed to the 3rd criteria parameter, causing the results to spill dynamically across. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM((FILTER($A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5=B14)>=$A$8)*(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5=B14)<=$B$8))
```

or

```
=LET(z,FILTER($A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5=B14),SUM((z>=$A$8)*(z<=$B$8)))
```

or to spill:

```
=MAP(B14:F14,LAMBDA(a,LET(z,FILTER($A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5=a),SUM((z>=$A$8)*(z<=$B$8)))))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant again!  Thanks so much for the reply.  Lots of cool options to try.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following formula with <kbd>MMULT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, --REPT(PublicHolidays[DATE],N(E2:I2=PublicHolidays[LOCATION])),
     φ, IFERROR((α>=Dates[Start Date])*(α<=Dates[End Date]),0),
     MMULT( SEQUENCE(,ROWS(φ),,0),φ))
```

---

Or, using <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> helper function <kbd>BYCOL()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, --REPT(PublicHolidays[DATE],N(E2:I2=PublicHolidays[LOCATION])),
     BYCOL((α>=Dates[Start Date])*(α<=Dates[End Date]),LAMBDA(φ, SUM(IFERROR(φ,0)))))
```

---

Note that with recent update in `MS365` for `Beta Channel` users can avoid the <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> construct to use <kbd>BYCOL()</kbd> just like shown below.

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, --REPT(PublicHolidays[DATE],N(E2:I2=PublicHolidays[LOCATION])),
     BYCOL(IFERROR((α>=Dates[Start Date])*(α<=Dates[End Date]),0),SUM))
```

---

Also note:

Where: `PublicHolidays` refers to table structured range: `A1:B5`

Where: `Dates` refers to table structured range: `A8:B9`

---

BTW, you can also use an <kbd>IF()</kbd> in place of <kbd>REPT()</kbd>

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, IF(E2:I2=PublicHolidays[LOCATION],PublicHolidays[DATE],""),
     BYCOL(IFERROR((α>=Dates[Start Date])*(α<=Dates[End Date]),0),SUM))
```

---

Comment: Brilliant!, Thanks so much for the prompt reply.  I will give these a go.